# How to unlock the file after move_uploaded_file()?

Tags: php

The php function, move_upload_file() leaves the new file locked. How to unlock the new file. However, after the php script stops, the lock is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
chmod(file path including file name)
```